# Why was the commandment on eating the fruit said in single?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit

The Torah says that G-d created "them":

> וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הָאָדָם ... זָכָר וּנְקֵבָה בָּרָא אֹתָם׃
>   And God created man ... male and female **He created them.**

Later He blesses *them*:

> וַיְבָרֶךְ אֹתָם אֱלֹהִים וַיֹּאמֶר לָהֶם אֱלֹהִים פְּרוּ וּרְבוּ ...׃
>   God blessed **them** and God said to **them**, “Be fertile and increase, f...”

After G-d (re-)creates Adam He commands him in single:

> וַיְצַו ה"א עַל־הָאָדָם לֵאמֹר מִכֹּל עֵץ־הַגָּן אָכֹל תֹּאכֵל׃
>   And the LORD God commanded the man, saying, “Of every tree of the garden you are free to eat;

What happened to "them"?

Comment: When you go from a narrative in more or less present tense to a summary or viewpoint from a bit or much, much later, events get telescoped.  Another example of this is the narrative of the siege of Jerusalem and the killing of Sennacherib by his sons--there were a good 20 years or so between the events, but they're narrated as if one directly followed the other.

Comment: The Torah of Moshe does not necessarily follow chronological sequence in the arrangement of the sentences. You are making a false assumption.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Between us, I thought that the first part is in אב"י and the last is עשיה and that has to follow, not to precede. Isn't it?

Comment: @AlBerko If you are referring to the kabbalistic fantasy (that many here deny) about multiple universes and multiple dimensions, everything that exists in those 'upper dimensions' manifests here in the lower dimension. (Meaning what you are calling עשיה.) The 'Tanninim' are a distinct & unique life form, of which there were originally only 2. In some places (like Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer if memory serves) the 'Nachash HaKadmoni' is associated to this subject.

Answer (score 4):

*Them is not created yet.*

The line you quoted Gen 2:16, Hashem is talking to Adam. It says it right there “Vayitzav H”E” Al HaAdam...”

Bereshis second chapter (hereafter Gen 2:) tells of creation details again starting with verse 4. Adam is created in Gen2:7.to Gan Eden in Gen 2:8. The commandment you quote is Gen 2:16-17. Woman is created after that in Gen 2:21-22.

Why the creation narrative is somewhat retold at that point is a whole ‘nother question.

Link to Bereshis 2 https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm

Comment: It appears that according to many interpreters (Rashi) that hold that they were created back to back (see my other question) and then only separated, you're wrong. So you might claim "according to the approach that the Torah is not consequential, ...".

Comment: I believe that the Torah is consequential. Did you mean a different word?

Comment: Sorry I meant אין מוקדם ומאוחר בתורה.

Comment: It's a good question. What was the nature of Adam Harishon at the point he (they?) was created? The p'shat is that t Gen:2 has just him until she is created from him. Gen 1 has both, whether they were in one form or separate.